# Apache 2.2 - "Allow from" only if QUERY_STRING matches

Tags: apache

I'm trying to limit one of my servers to only one specific request, but after 2 hours of trying couldn't come up with a working solution. Basically I'm looking for something similar to the `<If ...>` directive, but I only have Apache 2.2 (this is a fact, and I cannot update to 2.4).

I have 4 Servers: frontend[1-3] and backend1. frontend[1-2] are allowed to do anything on backend1, but frontend3 should only be allowed to make 1 specific request. In Apache 2.4 it would look something like this:

```
<Location />
    Order allow,deny

    Allow from frontend1
    Allow from frontend2

    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /foobar/myfunc/[^/]*$">
        Allow from frontend3
    </If>
</Location>
```

How can I do the same in Apache 2.2? I tried using SetEnvIf, but since it hasn't got logical AND it was a mess and didn't work (I have to match the host *and* the URL, since frontend3 is only allowed to do "myfunc").

Answer (score 0):

Found a way with the help of mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Matching the host "frontend3"
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4$
# Matching the request "/foobar/myfunc?do=something"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do=something$
# Setting an environment variable if host & request match
RewriteRule ^/foobar/myfunc$ - [E=allowthis:1,L]

<Location />
    Order allow,deny

    Allow from frontend1
    Allow from frontend2

    Allow from env=allowthis
</Location>
```